# How to grep in real time an output containing a progress bar?

Tags: grep, stdout, progress-information

I am using a tool (`openocd`) which is printing a lot of garbage, then a basic progress bar slowly printing simple dots, then again some garbage.

I would like to filter this output with `grep` so only the line with progress bar is shown, and in real time (i.e. each dot outputted by `openocd` is immediately printed in the terminal):

```
openocd <args> |& grep '^\.'
```

The problem is that `grep` is line buffered (at best) so the progress bar will not be shown until it is finished.

How can I do with `grep`, or is there any standard alternative to achieve this?
If there is a way through `openocd` configuration, this would be useful though I would prefer a more general solution.

Comment: Are you sure garbage and progress bar are both printed to the same file descriptor? If the garbage is printed to stderr, for example, you can redirect it out of the way.

Comment: @adc Unfortunately, openocd is sending all to stderr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a kind of hacky/unusual answer, the fact being that this is most likely possible in a not very clean way.

---

`grep` itself seems to only print output when it encounters a newline character, your progress bar likely does not introduce a newline character when it updates, hence your issue.

`strace` is a tool used to view the system calls that a command is calling, this includes things like reading and writing things to memory/storage, as well as things like opening/closing file descriptors.

---

With `strace` you can view what a process is accessing, in the case of your pipe `stout` is being passed to `grep`, so with `strace` you can view the text that's being fed to `grep`. `strace` will regularly be sent the output coming from the piped command, and you can sniff that output and display it. I was testing with `rsync --progress`, which seems to run into a similar scenario. I used `grep` on the `##%` because that's what `rsync` uses to show progress.

```
rsync --progress file1 file2 | strace -e trace=read grep "[0-9]*%"
```

If you run this command you'll find that `strace` doesn't have nice output, but that when I used it `strace` caught a couple of `read`s from the `rsync` that `grep` would not normally `write`, showing `read`s for 0%, 21%, 45%, 68%, 91% and 100%, seemed to update about every second (probably based on how often `rsync` updates the progress).

So with that you can `grep` the `strace` output, which is not very nice, by calling the same `grep` again.

```
rsync --progress file1 file2 | strace -e trace=read grep "[0-9]*%" 2>&1 > /dev/null | grep -o "[0-9]*%"
```

The `2>&1` is important because `strace` prints on `stderr`. The `> /dev/null` redirects `stdout` to `/dev/null` to prevent the output of the first `grep` being reported. The end result of this was the following output:

```
0%
21%
45%
68%
91%
100%
```

You'll have to swap out the `grep`, but it seems like it'll do the trick. It's not pretty, but it functions, and works around the restrictions of `grep`. Seems like a `grep -f` that works like `tail -f` would be handy (I know `grep -f` is already in use).

The first `grep` is mostly just to filter down the text that `strace` will be `read`ing, since only the matching lines will be listed in `strace`s `read` calls, but you also need something for the text to be moving through so `strace` can watch it.

Answer (score 4):

I am expending on Centimane answer as the final answer is quite complicated.

It was already quite hacky... it becomes now really crappy:

```
make flash \
    |& strace -e trace=read grep -e "^\." -e rror \
    |& stdbuf -o0 sed -ne 's/^.*"\.".*/\./p;/rror/p' \
    | stdbuf -o0 tr -d '\n' \
    ; echo
```

So the `make flash` above is calling `openocd`;

`strace` is using Centimane's hack explained above;

`sed` replace `read(0, ".", xxx)` lines by single `.`;

`tr` is keeping all the `.` on one line, and final echo is putting the only EOL.

In addition to that, `sed` and `tr` are called with `stdbuf -o0` which sets the stdout buffer size to 0 (because EOL removed), and `grep/sed` are also matching `(e)rror` to print some garbage in case of error.

I tried to factorize all this bloat to the bare minimum, but could not do better.

Note also that I am using zsh/Ubuntu 14.04, and I am not sure this can work on other Unix.